# Palindrome-testing Java program for an interview

Tags: java, interview-questions, palindrome

In an interview I was asked to write a function that would take an input word and return true if the word is a palindrome. At first I used an approach using `StringBuilder` but the interviewer said that wasn't allowed and to use a `for` loop instead. I scored 7/9 so I'm guessing it's possible to improve this:

```
public static boolean isPalinedrome(String word) {

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if(word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(word.length() - 1 - i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I added the following to the `main()` section to test

```
String input = "racecar";
if(isPalinedrome(input)) {
    System.out.println(input + " is a palinedrome");
} else {
    System.out.println(input + " is not a palinedrome");
}
```

The way I test it seems to be ugly. Is there a standard way to test a new function? I guess if you're in an advanced enough environment you would have test cases for JUnit to run against it, but anything simpler that could be done in an interview with a cloud IDE?

Comment: Before you start writing code you need to define what the requirements are. Is it just suppose to just handle ASCII characters or  does the palindrome checker need to handle anything more complicated like [combining diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) (and, if so, is it just looking for equality for a naive string reversal or [is it expecting the diacritics to still be applied to the same character when reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41550815/1509264))?

Comment: Your test isn't a test. You shouldn't test if `"racecar"` is a palindrome : you know it is. You should check that `isPalindrome("racecar")` returns `true`. If not, raise an exception or display a big fat error message.

Comment: They might be checking for spelling; is there a reason it's called `isPalinedrome()`?

Comment: Without knowing the "expense" in Java of reversing an array, would it be a valid test to simply convert the string to an array, and reverse it to another array and use an array compare?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's enough to loop until `word.length() / 2`, as this will compare the first half with the second half, so no need to go until the end.

As you use `word.length()` multiple times, you could extract it to a helper variable.

There is a typo in the method name.

As for testing, yes, JUnit is the way to go. In a cloud IDE, you could create a helper method that takes a single string, calls `isPalindrome` and prints the result. That way you can test multiple cases easily, by adding one line per case. It's important to try to cover corner cases and potentially interesting cases, not just the "happy path". For example:

- palindrome with even length
- palindrome with odd length
- single letter
- empty string
- non-palindromes

During an interview, it might also be worth mentioning the trade-off between comparing characters using `.charAt`, or using the array of characters returned by `.toCharArray`.

Comment: I'd also include a null check, unless the interviewer had said not to.

Comment: Also, _possibly_ neater, and maybe more performant (though I doubt it) to call `String.toCharArray()` and loop over that, rather than repeatedly calling `charAt()`, though the difference seems like it would be negligible.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave thanks, I added a paragraph at the end about the trade-off between `.charAt` and `toCharArray`. (The actual details of that left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: One thing... What to return in case of `null`. Gut feeling tells me `false`. Also, is a *blank* string a palindrome?

Comment: I would add to check for char spacing also.. I know it specifies `word` however `nurses run` is considered a palindrome also.. /pedant

Comment: Don't check for `null` unless for some reason you want to return true or false for it. If someone passes you a null reference, just let the NPE be thrown, cause neither return value makes much sense.

Comment: @cHao I **strongly** disagree. Failing early is safer and easier to debug that letting an NPE propagate from wherever it happens to. It is also likely, in the general case, that passing `null` might work _sometimes_ due to control flow. Modern Java practices recommend checking all method argument invariants and throwing if something is wrong. I would recommend against your suggestion in the strongest possible way.

Comment: You could also test the output for `"Hannah"`. It probably should be considered a palindrome. In this case, you'd need to compare lowercase characters.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: "Modern Java practices" would recommend (1) not allowing nulls to reach that point in the first place, and/or (2) throwing an exception for invalid arguments. Since a NPE is already going to happen when you try to call `word.length()`, you've gained nothing by checking, except for an implication that that value might be null.

Comment: @cHao yes, but one cannot assume that they haven't. And `null` is an invalid argument. You gain throwing an exception with a sensible message from a sensible place rather than an exception with no message from some random place. As I said above, in the general case, if you do not check for `null` then you cannot be sure that the method doesn't work _somethimes_ with `null`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I don't care about the general case. I care about _this_ case. And in this case, if `word` is null, you know exactly where the NPE gets thrown. _In this function._ _Consistently._ You gain nothing.

Answer (score 2):

JUnit tests would be a rather nice way to go here, as you correctly assume.
It does not take much:

- import `org.junit.Test`
- statically import your asserts (e.g. `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals`)
- annotate your test with `@Test`

and you're good to go.

Pity your interviewer went for the `for` loop, palindromes can be nicely solved by recursion (pointing out the performance and memory usage drawbacks, of course.. )

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class PalindromeTesterClass {

    @Test
    public void shouldRecognizeNull() {
        assertEquals(false, PalindromeTesterClass.isPalindrome(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRecognizeEmptyString() {
        assertEquals(true, PalindromeTesterClass.isPalindrome(""));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRecognizeOneCharacterPalindrome() {
        assertEquals(true, PalindromeTesterClass.isPalindrome("a"));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRecognizeTwoCharacterPalindrome() {
        assertEquals(true, PalindromeTesterClass.isPalindrome("aa"));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRecognizeTwoCharacterNonPalindrome() {
        assertEquals(false, PalindromeTesterClass.isPalindrome("ab"));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRecognizePalindrome() {
        assertEquals(true, PalindromeTesterClass.isPalindrome("amanaplanacanalpanama"));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRecognizeNonPalindrome() {
        assertEquals(false, PalindromeTesterClass.isPalindrome("noPalindrome"));
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
        if (word == null) {
            // assuming a null value is no palindrome
            return false;
        } else if (word.length() < 2) {
            // assuming both "" and "x" are palindromes
            return true;
        } else {
            // a word is a palindrome if it starts and ends in the same letter..
            if (!word.endsWith(word.substring(0, 1))) {
                return false;
            }
            // .. and everything in between the first and the last letter is a palindrome
            return isPalindrome(word.substring(1, word.length() - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case I'd use `assertTrue`, in my opinion `assertTrue(PalindromeTesterClass.isPalindrome("aba"));` is more readable and coincise.

Comment: I really don't see why this recursion approach would be nicer than a simple for loop. It's wordier, slower, and (in my opinion) less intuitive. Tests look fine though.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you should compare *code points*, not `char`s. In Java, char doesn't necessarily represent a whole character, so for out-of-order comparison it won't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

***fastest solution***

```
 public static boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
    int n = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < (n / 2); ++i) {
        if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(n - i - 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```